# Python anotation arrow direction

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, plot-annotations

I am trying to annotate a scatter plot in Python 2.7, with Matplotlib. Here is the plot code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5,3), columns=list('ABC'))
df.insert(0,'Annotation_Text',['ABC','DEF','GHI','JKL','mnop'])

q = 2
pqr = 1

# Scatter Plot:
x = df['A']
y = df.iloc[:,q]
plt.scatter(x, y, marker='o', label = df.columns.tolist()[q])

# Plot annotation:
plt.annotate(df.iloc[pqr,0]+', (%.2f, %.2f)' % (x.ix[pqr],y.ix[pqr]), xy=(x.ix[pqr], y.ix[pqr]), xycoords='data', xytext = (x.ix[pqr], y.ix[pqr]), textcoords='offset points', arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='-|>'))

# Axes title/legend:
plt.xlabel('xlabel', fontsize=18)
plt.ylabel('ylabel', fontsize=16)
plt.legend(scatterpoints = 1)

plt.show()
```

As you can see, the main line is the line starting with `plt.annotate(df.iloc[pqr,0]+', (%...............`.

I think that the main problem is with this part of the `plt.annotate()` line: `xytext = (x.ix[pqr], y.ix[pqr]), textcoords='offset points', arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='-|>')`. From here, `xytext = (x.ix[pqr], y.ix[pqr])` is just a tuple of the x and y co-ordinates of the data point to be annotated. Unfortunately, this is placing the annotation right at the data point, which I do not want. I want to leave some blank space between the data point and the annotation text.

Also, I am having a problem with the arrow and annotation that this line is producing. See below.
[image: Annotation Image]

**Problems:**

- Currently, the annotation text is overlapping the arrow. The annotation text is too close to the data point. I don't want it to be so close.
- Also the arrow is pointing from right to left. I don't think I asked it to plot the arrow from right-to-left, so I don't know why it is plotting the arrow in this direction.

Is there a way to control the text annotation so that there is no overlap with the data point? Also, how do I change the arrow direction from right-to-left to the either a) the `best` direction or b) from left-to-right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `plt.annotate(...)`, `xy` gives the position of the data you want to point at (one end of the arrow) and `xytext` gives the position of your text. In your code, they are overlapping because you specified the same positions for `xy` and `xytext`. Try this instead (for example):

```
plt.annotate(df.iloc[pqr,0]+', (%.2f, %.2f)' % (x.ix[pqr], y.ix[pqr]), xy=(x.ix[pqr], y.ix[pqr]), xycoords='data', xytext=(x.ix[pqr], y.ix[pqr]+0.3), arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='-|>'), horizontalalignment='center')
```

The arrow by default is pointing from the text to the data point. If you want to change the direction of the arrow, you can use `arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='<|-')`

Comment: Thank you. So, regarding `xytext=(,)`, if I try this `xy=(10,10),xytext=(10-0.1,10-0.1)`, does this mean that the annotation text starts at `(9.9,9.9)` or `(0.099,0.099)`? .i.e. what are the units of `xytext=(,)` and what are the units of `xy=(,)`?

Comment: By default `xycoords` and `textcoords` should be `data`. So, in this case, the text will be at (9.9, 9.9). You can change that if that is not your desired coordinates (if you want your text to follow your data, `data` seems like the logical choice).

Comment: @JulienSpronck could I ask you please what you mean by "data"?  I am trying to give xytext and xy the same values just to see if I get an arrow that overlaps on the chart but I get an error when I do this.  When I set xytext =0 the chart plots without error but I don't see any arrow.  I am using ax1.annotate("", xy=(1999, 12000000), xytext=(0, 0),arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->")) and the ax1 axis runs between 800,000 and 1,900,000.  Any help most welcome!